# Determine the following indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{289x^2-289}}$

The only technique we have learned is the reverse power rule since we have just started this concept. How would I go about solving this with only the reverse power rule?

Comment: I suppose you have learned the elementary antiderivatives?

Comment: Yes we have just started the concepts of antiderivatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $17^2$=289 we can rewrite the integral as $\frac{1}{17}\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ and then we use the substitution $y=\sqrt(x^2-1)$) to obtain $\int \frac{dy}{1+y^2}$ which is arctan(y).

Hence we have $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{289x^2-289}}$=$\frac{arctan(sqrt{(x^2-1)})}{17} +C$. This is integration using inverse trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an elementary antiderivative.

$\displaystyle \int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{289x^2-289}}  $

Bring out the constant $\sqrt{289}=17$

Now,

$ \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{17}\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}  $

Note that this is a standard antiderivative. 
$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sec^{-1} (x)=\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.

Here,$ \sec^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of $\sec(x)$

So the integral is $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{17} \sec^{-1} (x ) +C$

Comment: Actually the derivative of $\sec^{-1} x$ is $\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.

Comment: True. Also, the actual antiderivative is $\sec^{-1}|x|$, but this needs justification why the modulus comes in (like why $\int \frac{1}{x}dx$ is $\ln |x|$ but not $\ln x$). Since OP is just starting on integration, I was not certain if he had learned about that yet.